# Converting a JS object to an array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

My application creates a JavaScript object, like the following:

```
myObj= {1:[Array-Data], 2:[Array-Data]}
```

But I need this object as an array.

```
array[1]:[Array-Data]
array[2]:[Array-Data]
```

So I tried to convert this object to an array by iterating with `$.each` through the object and adding the element to an array:

```
x=[]
$.each(myObj, function(i,n) {
    x.push(n);});
```

Is there an better way to convert an object to an array or maybe a function?

Comment: Should the array indices be the same as keys in original object? First index in an array is always 0, but your own code and most answers (including the accepted one) seem to ignore it; still, you've reverted my edit to desired example result.

Comment: Yes, you are right: first Array element starts with 0. But I reverted your edit, because it was not consistent in my eyes to keep that example simple as possible, because changing `myObj= {1:[Array-Data]` to `myObj= {0:[Array-Data]` was not part of your edit (as I remember right)

Comment: Use the jQuery **$.makeArray(obj)** command for that http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

Comment: @DevlshOne the documentation u provided says: "Turn a jQuery object into an array" i dont think this fits on OP question

Answer (score 762, accepted):

If you are looking for a functional approach:

```
var obj = {1: 11, 2: 22};
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
```

Results in:

```
[11, 22]
```

The same with an ES6 arrow function:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key])
```

With ES7 you will be able to use `Object.values` instead ([more information](http://www.2ality.com/2015/11/stage3-object-entries.html)):

```
var arr = Object.values(obj);
```

Or if you are already using Underscore/Lo-Dash:

```
var arr = _.values(obj)
```

Comment: @KarelBílek Is iteration order for a JS object ever guaranteed? ['An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function.'](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

Comment: Unsatisfied with the top answer, I just wrote this almost exact function, came back to post it as an answer, scrolled down, saw 170. Realized, man If I hadn't given up I wouldn't have had to think :) This should be at the top. OP pls select as answer.

Comment: for anyone for whom this is not obvious, the keys don't need to be sequential (i.e. in this example they are 1 and 2 - but they could just as well be a string key or non sequential number

Comment: For the first paragraph of code I get missing semi-colon. Not sure why.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle I guess your linter requires to write "return obj[key];" with a semicolon in the end. JavaScript does not though.

Comment: While browsers like chrome seem to automatically sort Objects if they have numeric keys, that doesn't seem to actually be part of the *standard* (i.e. ordering of object keys is implementation-defined and `Object.keys` could easily come out with `[5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 0]` in a different browser while remaining standards-compliant, which would be bad if ordering is important). Suggested change: `Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b)=>+a - +b).map(key=>obj[key])`. Just to guarantee that it comes in order. Also, the `+a - +b` guarantees that the keys are interpreted as numbers and are sorted numerically.

Answer (score 448):

```
var myObj = {
    1: [1, 2, 3],
    2: [4, 5, 6]
};

var array = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});


console.log(array);
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: No the array gets flattened as Marko commented on my post

Comment: sorry i didn't notice the square brackets!

Comment: hey - this works well. :-) Do you think, this is an "better" way to convert objects to arrays as my solution? Because i try to keep that code simple and transparent as possible. -easy to understand for others.

Comment: @Dogbert, please could you explain the `$.map`? Every search I try to do on this just turns up lots of links to jQuery or the map method of arrays.

Comment: D'oh! Ignore my comment. I hadn't noticed the jQuery tag on this question.

Comment: is there a way to maintain the keys in the new array?
every answer on the www i see lacks the conversion of keys.

Comment: You can also do this without jQuery:                 Object.keys(myObject).map(function(val) { return [val] });

Comment: @TD_Nijboer Yes, use `value.key = index; return [value];` instead of `return [value];`

Comment: you can get name of key using index parameter!!

Comment: @TD_Nijboer If you don't want the key to pollute the object data, then you can store the key in the second column of a two-dimensional array; just change the return line to this: `return [[value, index]]`

Comment: @10basetom, i believe now that the correct answer on my own question was that Javascript doesn't support associative arrays. i have fixed my issue in the mean time.

Comment: If you want to do it in javascript, and you need values instead of keys, this may help: Object.keys(obj).map(function(val) { return obj[val] }); - credits: Kris Erickson's comment

Comment: If you dont mind excluding IE then use `Object.values(obj);`

Comment: I made a dozen search to solve this problem and no one was so simple and effective. Thanks man, you saved my weekend. Now it's possible to involve grep for additional filter...! Great

Answer (score 34):

Simply do

```
Object.values(obj);
```

That's all!

Comment: Object.values is an ES2017 method that is not supported in Safari, IE, Node 6.

Comment: Object.values  is supported in Safari 10.1+, Node 7+

Comment: I would prefer people to read other answers before posting. Joel's answer already contained this info (with more detail) on Mar 11, 2016 -- nearly a year before this was posted. This sort of an answer, as with several below, don't add anything that isn't already here & just make it harder to find actual varied replies. IDK if this is just intentional reputation farming, or if people regularly neglect due diligence when writing answers.

Answer (score 30):

I think you can use `for in` but checking if the property is not inerithed

```
myObj= {1:[Array-Data], 2:[Array-Data]}
var arr =[];
for( var i in myObj ) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
       arr.push(myObj[i]);
    }
}
```

EDIT - if you want you could also keep the indexes of your object, but you have to check if they are numeric (and you get undefined values for missing indexes:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

myObj= {1:[1,2], 2:[3,4]}
var arr =[];
for( var i in myObj ) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        if (isNumber(i)){
            arr[i] = myObj[i];
        }else{
          arr.push(myObj[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have tested the code. `$.map` will flatten `Array-Data`.

Comment: you are right i didn't test it with an array and map flattens it! i modified the answer

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti $.makeArray() sounds good, but is not what I was looking for, because it simply puts the object to an array element: `[{1:[Array-Data], 2:[Array-Data]}]`
And `$.map()` also doesn't look successful. It seams, that all Sub-Array data is merged to one array. `array.length` should return 2 (because 2 elements exists), but it returns 67 which is the number of all elements in all ["Array-Data"].

Comment: @The Bndr i posted another solution, but you can use map as suggested by dogbert

Comment: I think you must explicitly specify the array index... like `arr[+i] = myObj[i];` because (i) `for(...in...)` is not guaranteed to return properties in any order (ii) in OP's example the properties start from 1, not 0.

Comment: I used push as a general way to convert an object into an array, because if the property is not a number you end up creating an object, otherwise you create an array with 3 elements (the element with index 0 is undefined)

Comment: Ok i posted a solution that keeps the indexes if they are numeric but in this case you get an array with 3 elements (the element with index 0 is undefined)

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti the solution i looked for was more that one from Dogbert. But reading you ideas, and alternative solutions was very interesting for my - to rise the own horizon. Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

If you know the maximum index in you object you can do the following:

```js
var myObj = {
    1: ['c', 'd'],
    2: ['a', 'b']
  },
  myArr;

myObj.length = 3; //max index + 1
myArr = Array.prototype.slice.apply(myObj);
console.log(myArr); //[undefined, ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]
```

Comment: It would be far better for the code that is generating the object to also set the length or indeed make it an array in the first place. I don't expect either are possible, so this answer for me isn't helpful.

Comment: `myObj.length = Object.keys(myObj).length`

Answer (score 19):

Since ES5 Object.keys() returns an array containing the properties defined directly on an object (excluding properties defined in the prototype chain):

```
Object.keys(yourObject).map(function(key){ return yourObject[key] });
```

ES6 takes it one step further with arrow functions:

```
Object.keys(yourObject).map(key => yourObject[key]);
```

Comment: For the current ES5 (although I do enjoy ES6): Object.keys(yourObject).map(function(key){ return yourObject[key] });

Answer (score 18):

Nowadays, there is a simple way to do this : **Object.values()**.

```
var myObj = {
    1: [1, 2, 3],
    2: [4, 5, 6]
};

console.log(Object.values(myObj));
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

This doesn't required jQuery, it's been defined in ECMAScript 2017.
It's supported by every modern browser (forget IE).

Comment: if i do something like `var  state = {
    ingredient: {
      salad: 1,
      bacon: 1,
    }
  }` and then

`var HariOm = Object.values(state);` followed by `console.log(typeof HariOM)` it displays the type as an object. Shouldn't it display it as an array?

Comment: That's completely normal, check the reference here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Description - You can use `Array.isArray(HariOM)`

Answer (score 17):

The best method would be using a javascript -only function:

```
var myArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(myObj, 0);
```

Comment: @Qwerty which browser?

Comment: Chrome. Tested with `var myObj = {1:[1,2,3],2:[4,5,6]};`

Comment: Note that this method works for converting "array-like objects", meaning they've got to have a "length" property and enumerated properties counting up from 0.  So, to make @Qwerty's example work try this: {0:[1,2,3], 1:[4,5,6], length:2}.  Experiment with index values and length values, it's a little lenient.  Here's a good read on the topic: http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/  Skip down to "Array-like Objects".

Answer (score 15):

```
x = [];
for( var i in myObj ) {
    x[i] = myObj[i];
}
```

Comment: You should use push, otherwise you might end up creating an object

Comment: Maybe It is some better force to int the index.
`var bbb = {'1': 'a', '3': 'b'};
var x = [];
for (var i in bbb) { x[parseInt(i)] = bbb[i];}
console.log(x);`

Answer (score 15):

**ECMASCRIPT 5:**

```
Object.keys(myObj).map(function(x) { return myObj[x]; })
```

**ECMASCRIPT 2015 or ES6:**

```
Object.keys(myObj).map(x => myObj[x])
```

Answer (score 13):

How about `jQuery.makeArray(obj)`

This is how I did it in my app.

Comment: This returns [Object] for the above example.

Comment: just a matter of adding [0] index and you saved my life :)

Answer (score 7):

**ES8 way** *made easy*:

[The official documentation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-fundamental-objects)

```js
    const obj = { x: 'xxx', y: 1 };
    let arr = Object.values(obj); // ['xxx', 1]
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 6):

The solving is very simple

```
var my_obj = {1:[Array-Data], 2:[Array-Data]}
Object.keys(my_obj).map(function(property_name){ 
    return my_obj[property_name]; 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/eVHB2/)</kbd>

Extension to answer of [bjornd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367960/bjornd) .

```
var myObj = {
    1: [1, [2], 3],
    2: [4, 5, [6]]
}, count = 0,
    i;
//count the JavaScript object length supporting IE < 9 also
for (i in myObj) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        count++;
    }
}
//count = Object.keys(myObj).length;// but not support IE < 9
myObj.length = count + 1; //max index + 1
myArr = Array.prototype.slice.apply(myObj);
console.log(myArr);
```

---

Reference

[Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

[Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

[Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys)

Comment: I might be wrong, but should it be better for myObj to be an enumerable starting at 0 ? 

Else what, it seems to me that there we have an issues where our Array would be : 
[undefined,[1,[2],3]] 

(The first part is undefined because it don't find myObj['0'] and the last part myObj['2'] being ejected because after reading .length it stop at myObj['1']?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the name of the object's properties as values. Example:

```
var fields = {
    Name: { type: 'string', maxLength: 50 },
    Age: { type: 'number', minValue: 0 }
}
```

Use `Object.keys()`, `Array.map()` and `Object.assign()`:

```
var columns = Object.keys( fields ).map( p => Object.assign( fields[p], {field:p} ) )
```

*Result:*

```
[ { field: 'Name', type: 'string', maxLength: 50 }, 
  { field: 'Age', type: 'number', minValue: 0 } ]
```

*Explanation:*

`Object.keys()` enumerates all the properties of the source ; `.map()` applies the `=>` function to each property and returns an Array ; `Object.assign()` merges name and value for each property.

Answer (score 1):

I made a custom function:

```
    Object.prototype.toArray=function(){
    var arr=new Array();
    for( var i in this ) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            arr.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, here is a general object to array function convertor:

**You have the object:**

```
var obj = {
    some_key_1: "some_value_1"
    some_key_2: "some_value_2"
};
```

**The function:**

```
function ObjectToArray(o)
{
    var k = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o);
    var v = Object.values(o);

    var c = function(l)
    {
        this.k = [];
        this.v = [];
        this.length = l;
    };

    var r = new c(k.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
    {
        r.k[i] = k[i];
        r.v[i] = v[i];
    }

    return r;
}
```

**Function Use:**

```
var arr = ObjectToArray(obj);
```

**You Get:**

> ```
> arr {
>     key: [
>         "some_key_1",
>         "some_key_2"
>     ],
>     value: [
>         "some_value_1",
>         "some_value_2"
>     ],
>     length: 2
> }
> ```

So then you can reach all keys & values like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    console.log(arr.key[i] + " = " + arr.value[i]);
}
```

**Result in console:**

> ```
> some_key_1 = some_value_1
> some_key_2 = some_value_2
> ```

**Edit:**

Or in prototype form:

```
Object.prototype.objectToArray = function()
{
    if (
        typeof this != 'object' ||
        typeof this.length != "undefined"
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    var k = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
    var v = Object.values(this);

    var c = function(l)
    {
        this.k = [];
        this.v = [];
        this.length = l;
    };

    var r = new c(k.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
    {
        r.k[i] = k[i];
        r.v[i] = v[i];
    }

    return r;
};
```

**And then use like:**

```
console.log(obj.objectToArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function to do the conversion from `object` to `array`, something like this can do the job for you using pure javascript:

```
var objectToArray = function(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  if ('object' !== typeof obj || 'undefined' === typeof obj || Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj;
  } else {
    Object.keys(obj).map(x=>arr.push(obj[x]));
  }
  return arr;
};
```

or this one:

```
var objectToArray = function(obj) {
  var arr =[];
  for(let o in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
      arr.push(obj[o]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
};
```

and call and use the function as below:

```
var obj = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e'};
objectToArray(obj); // return ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Also in the future we will have something called `Object.values(obj)`, similar to `Object.keys(obj)` which will return all properties for you as an array, but not supported in many browsers yet...