# JQuery Datatables Row Data From AJAX Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

In the past I've always used this to get a hidden column's data. I would hide the column with a css class, but the responsive feature doesn't work well with these.

```
var td = $('td', this);
var ID = $(td[0]).text();
```

So I found an alternative, by hiding the columns with these classes with the responsive feature.

```
"columnDefs": [
    //Responsive classes
    { className: 'never', targets: 0 }, //Hide on all devices
    { className: 'all', targets: 1 },   //Show on all devices
]
```

and then I use either one of these.

```
var rowData = oTable1.fnGetData(this);
var rowData = oTable1.api().row(this).data();

//Grab the first indexed item in the list
var ID = rowData[0];
```

That works well if you don't have an AJAX source. It will return a comma separated list of the row data. However, when I try to use this with an AJAX source I just get [object Object] back (instead of a comma separated list) if I output the rowData variable in an alert.

How do I get the row data out of a table with an AJAX source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an answer I found here.
[Converting a JS object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/a-better-way-to-convert-js-object-to-array)

I can pull the entire row data from the table with this.

```
 var rowData = oTable1.api().row(this).data();
```

In the console log I can see that it returns a javascript object like this.

```
 Object { id="123456", full_name="Samuel Smith", Last_name="Smith" }
```

I use this function to convert the object into an array.

```
var array = $.map(rowData, function (value, index) {
        return [value];
    });
```

In the console log, my array would appear like this.

```
["123456", "Samuel Smith", "Smith"]
```

I can then extract any item from the array like this.

```
alert(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seem to be stored as string so [1, 2, 3] became [object Object] when you turn it into string. Do `yourString = yourList.join(',')` and store yourString to keep the coma-separated string.

For an object:

```
yourString = (function () {
  var list = [];
  for(var i in yourList)
    if(yourList.hasOwnProperty(i))
      list.push(yourList[i]);
  return list.join(',');
})();
```

The function is not needed, it's just to limit the variables scope.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer, but I'm getting this
    TypeError: rowData.join is not a function

Comment: If I output to console, I can see the object formatted as Object { id="123456", full_name="Sarah Smith", Last_name="Smith"} for example.  I just need to pull out those individual values.

Comment: I edit it with an object example. If it's not what you want, please precise exactly what you have in input and what you what as output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  Looking in the console log helped me figure this out.  I thought it was just a comma separated string I needed, which is what you helped me create, but I need an array.  What was being returned without the AJAX source was an array.  That's why I could use something like alert(rowData[0]); to get the first value.  I was confused looking at rowData in an alert instead of the console log.
So, with an Ajax source,my function returns an object instead of an array, which I then convert to an array so I can get an individual value.  I'll explain more in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying madvora's example:

```
var rowData = oTable1.api().row(this).data().to$();
rowDataArray = rowData.toArray();
```