# How to get required Object from JavaScript array Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have created an array of objects which is given below. I want that if I would like to get value from the object which is at any index. When I alert the object using following code it does show start character of the object.

```
<script>
    var products = {
        DiseaseType: "Respiratory",
        Pathogens: "Actinobacillus   pleuropneumoniae",
        Product: "DRAXXIN® Injectable Solution (tulathromycin)",
        RouteofAdministration: "Injectable",
        DiseaseType: "Respiratory",
        Pathogens: "Actinobacillus pleuropneumoniae",
        Product: "DRAXXIN® 25 Injectable Solution (tulathromycin)",
        RouteofAdministration: "Injectable",
        DiseaseType: "Respiratory",
        Pathogens: "Actinobacillus pleuropneumoniae",
        Product: "EXCEDE® For Swine Sterile Suspension (ceftiofur crystalline free  acid)",
        RouteofAdministration: "Injectable"
    };


alert(products.DiseaseType[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: {} is object, [] is array

Comment: `DiseaseType` is a _key_ and not _array_.

Comment: Thanks But If we want to make array of Objects using this data how to access that

Comment: You don't have to put [0] just try alert(products.DiseaseType);

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/a-better-way-to-convert-js-object-to-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of objects like this :

```
var products = [{...},{...},{...}]
```

You can access to a object property with this code :

```
alert(products[0].DiseaseType);
```

Answer (score 0):

`products` is an object, not an array. To access its values simply call:

```
alert(products.DiseaseType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are assigning scalar values to the element of the object. Hence, this would not return any thing:

```
alert(products.DiseaseType[0]);
```

Because you have not declared them like this:

```
var products = {
        DiseaseType: ["Respiratory"],
        }
```

Just remove the brackets:

```
alert(products.DiseaseType[0]);
```

With `{}` you care object which do not allows you to access its element using numeric indexes, while `[]` allows you to declare an array and access its element numerically.

Since `String` is really, under the hood, not more than an array of character, the following:

```
var myname = "Robert";
console.log(myname[0]);
```

returns `R` because it is treated internally as an array of:

```
["R", "o", "b", "e", "r", "t"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an object not array so rather call like this

```
alert(products.DiseaseType);
```