# How to convert object to array

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have an `json` data having property `attributes.data`. When I `console.log(attributes.data)` this value I get the result `{"uid" : 1}` I want to convert this to an array.
i.e `{"uid" : 1}` and so on I want to convert this to form data `uid:1`. how I will do that in javascripts.

```js
 if (attributes.type == "POST") {
   xmlhttp.open(attributes.type, attributes.url, true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
   attributes.data = JSON.stringify(attributes.data);
   xmlhttp.send(attributes.data);
 }
```

while debug in chrome Network tab i have the form data {"uid" :1} but i want to get this like uid: 1 how do i convert it to that

Comment: see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/a-better-way-to-convert-js-object-to-array or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array

Comment: If what you mean is an associative array, you can access Javascript objects (like {"uid" : 1} ) with a syntax like `arr['uid']`

Comment: i want POST this using ajax so i want to get this like uid:1

Comment: It is not clear (to me) what exactly do you want to achieve...

Comment: i have to post data using ajax and the form data must be like this uid:1 but i have the data in the following form {"uid" : 1}. how i convert this to uid:1

Comment: how i convert this data in in this type

Comment: no i have no other attribute

Comment: If it's a string just replace the {, }, " and spaces with nothing I'm sure there's a nifty regex or use one of the 2 identical solutions posted

Comment: i have try the below solution but these are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you need is to have an array with values like so: `['uid:1', 'key:value', ...]`

Then this would work:

```js
var attribute = {
    data: {
      "uid": 1,
      "key2": 'value',
      "key3": 'value'

    }
  },
  key,
  myString = '';

for (key in attribute.data) {

  //this is the line that you want
  myString += "&" + key + ":" + attribute.data[key];
}


//the output of the fist element (there is only one now)
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = myString; // "uid:1"
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

if you want a string with ONLY the "uid" element

```js
var attribute = {
    data: {
      "uid": 1,
    }
  },
  key,
  myString = '';

for (key in attribute.data) {

  //this is the line that you want
  if (key === "uid") {
    myString = key + ":" + attribute.data[key]
  }
}


//the output of the fist element (there is only one now)
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = myString; // "uid:1"
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: please do a favor when use xhr.send(myArray); the form Data in network tab looks like 0:{........} but i want the data like this uid: 1

Comment: if you just want "uid:1" then use xhr.send(myArray[0]) - where "0" relates to the index of "uid" in the data object. HOWEVER, this implementation is overkill just to get "uid:1"

Comment: I edited both of my answers  to show option 1 create a url string where values are separated by "&" // option 2: only get the string for "uid".

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to simply convert your object into an array, this would do the job:

```
var obj = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key32":"value3","key4":"value4"};
var arr = [];
for (key in obj) {
   arr.push(key + ':' + obj[key]);
}
```

If What you actually want is to post your data as a string using AJAX, then using the given `obj` object you should just do:

```
var dataStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: i have the data in following format {"uid" :1} and i want this data in following pattern uid:1 how i can get this

Comment: @NoSpeakingGuy I don't get it. What pattern is that: uid:1 ...? How would your "array" look with the given data i provided in my answer?

Comment: Apologize, i want to convert {"uid" : 1} to form data. i.e used in ajax post method. uid:1

Comment: thanks, but i have used JSON.stringify(obj) as shown is question. so i have result {"uid" : 1}. now i want to make it just like this uid:1 want to remove all the parenthesis, colons etc.

Comment: do some in favor of me you are too close to answer i think.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is not a valid thing... why do you want to get rid of the "....?

Comment: I've updated my answer again (the first section), i think this will satisfy :-)

Comment: i have just add more discription in my question please  have a look