# Jquery substring/split

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

`$("#ELEMENT").TEXT()` is giving me and html string.

```
<div id="ELEMENT">
{
    "products": [
        {
            "TPNB": "52260983",
            "name": "name1",
            "price": 0.89,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "TPNB": "73559869",
            "name": "name2",
            "price": 1.1,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "TPNB": "51447540",
            "name": "Tesco Dijon Mustard 185g",
            "price": 0.55,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "TPNB": "61227739",
            "name": "name3150ml",
            "price": 0.6,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "TPNB": "56925638",
            "name": "Tesco Chicken Thighs 1kg",
            "price": 2.5,
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ]
}
</div>
```

I want to extract this `Array` into following index

1. `"TPNB":"52260983","name":"name1","price":0.89,"quantity":1`
2. `"TPNB":"52260983","name":"name2","price":0.89,"quantity":1`
3. `"TPNB":"56925638","name":"name13","price":2.5,"quantity":2`

Comment: Refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/a-better-way-to-convert-js-object-to-array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parsedJson = JSON.parse($("#ELEMENT").text())
var finalArray = new Array()
for (var i in parsedJson.products)
{
    finalArray.push(parsedJson.products[i]);
}
for (var i in finalArray)
{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(finalArray[i]).replace("{", "").replace("}", ""))  
}
```

after this you can access properties as such

```
finalArray[0].TPNB
finalArray[0].name
finalArray[0].price
finalArray[0].quantity
```

for the full code open you browser console and check out this http://jsfiddle.net/5wd29qch/1/

Comment: it is not a json object... i am featching values from a render html page.. $("#someelementid").text(); and i am getting a whole string

Comment: what string are you getting?

Comment: Pls see my question , I have modified it slightly. Thanks

Comment: i edited my response if i understand correctly you want to extract the values from the products key into an array

Comment: Thanks.. it seems to be working fine but there is slight change how i want to populate this. i want output similar to this.. we need to find sub string after comma. I want to print TPNB, NAME ,PRICE , QTY IN one string

Output should be

"TPNB":"52260983","name":"name1","price":0.89,"quantity":1
"TPNB":"52260983","name":"name2","price":0.89,"quantity":1
"TPNB":"56925638","name":"name13","price":2.5,"quantity":2


At present it is printing
50507235
Tesco Limes Each
0.3
13 1

Comment: I updated the code and jsfiddle, let me know if this is the result you want

Answer (score 0):

If the text is a valid json, you can parse it and get the `products` property which is the array you want:

```
var raw = $("#ELEMENT").text(),
    parsed = JSON.parse(raw),
    products = parsed.products;

console.log(products);
console.log(products[0]);
console.log(products[1]);
console.log(products[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var jsonData = // ur data from .text()
    var productData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    var productRows = productData.products;
    for(var i = 0; i < productRows.length; i++)
    {
          alert(productRows[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Try to add a full answer, not only the code, and also use an array to populate it with values, not an alert

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var json = $.parseJSON($('#ELEMENT').text());

json.products.map(function(v, i){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(v).replace('{','').replace('}',''));
});
```

**Output:**

```
"TPNB":"52260983","name":"name1","price":0.89,"quantity":1
"TPNB":"73559869","name":"name2","price":1.1,"quantity":1
"TPNB":"51447540","name":"Tesco Dijon Mustard 185g","price":0.55,"quantity":1
"TPNB":"61227739","name":"name3150ml","price":0.6,"quantity":1
"TPNB":"56925638","name":"Tesco Chicken Thighs 1kg","price":2.5,"quantity":2
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks,
One question, can we store new values in a variable.

Comment: Try this and let me know - [Working Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mrbjc4Lr/). Here, all the values will be stored in an array called 'newArray'. You can access any value by just calling newArray[0] or newArray[1] or newArray[2] etc.