# How to iterate JSON object in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, loops

Let's say I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    "A": [
            {"name": "Aa", "count": "21"},
            {"name": "Ab", "count": "54"}
         ],

    "B": [
            {"name": "Ba", "count": "30"},
            {"name": "Bb", "count": "22"}
         ],

    "C": [
            {"name": "Ca", "count": "40"},
            {"name": "Cb", "count": "33"}
         ],
}
```

Output HTML should like this:

```
[A]
Aa 21
Ab 54

[B]
Ba 30
Bb 22

[C]
Ca 40
Cb 33
```

How can I iterate using **angular2 Beta** version?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ng-for directive.

Have a look at this.
[angular-2-ng-for-syntax](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-ng-for-syntax)

And you should convert your object to an array. Have a look here: [a-better-way-to-convert-js-object-to-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/a-better-way-to-convert-js-object-to-array)