# From js object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is the quickest way in Javascript to transform an object from?

```
var test = {0:"obj 0", 1:"obj 1" 5:"obj 5"}
```

to:

```
["obj 0", "obj 1", "", "", "", "obj 5"]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6857636/4341456

Comment: The quickest way is to ask on SO and let someone write code for you.