# What is the simplest, briefest way to convert an object or an ArrayLikeObject to an array using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Given an object

```
  var obj = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"};
```

and expected result

```
  var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

or an [ArrayLikeObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#ArrayLikeObject)

```
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
```

with expected result

```
  var arr = [<div>a</div>, <div>b</div>, <div>c</div>];
```

The expected results could be returned using `$.map()` as described at

- [Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)
- [Converting a JS object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/a-better-way-to-convert-js-object-to-array)

Question:

What is the simplest, briefest approach using jQuery to convert an object or an ArrayLikeObject to an array ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.merge()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

> `jQuery.merge( first, second )`
>
> **first**
>   Type: ArrayLikeObject
>   The first array-like object to merge, the elements of second added.
>
> **second**
>   Type: ArrayLikeObject
>   The second array-like object to merge into the first, unaltered.

```js
var obj = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"};
var arr = $.merge([], obj);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

---

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var arr = $.merge([], divs);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

```js
var obj = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"};
var arr = $.extend([], obj);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var arr = $.extend([], divs);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With array-like objects, you can use [`jQuery.makeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/). (Also, with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).)

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(divs);

function foo() {
    return jQuery.makeArray(arguments);
}

foo(1, 'bar', false); // [1, 'bar', false]
```

---

It can also nearly work for the 1st object, but it'll need to be given a `length` (set to 1 + the greatest, positive, integer property).

```
var obj = { 0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", length: 3 };
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(obj);
```

If the `length` is unknown, you could figure it out first (ref: [9.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects)):

```
var obj = { 0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c" };

obj.length = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (prev, key) {
    var index = parseInt(key, 10);

    // 9.4.2 Array Exotic Objects
    // A String property name P is an array index if and only if...
    // ... ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P...
    var isInteger = key === String(index);
    // ... and ToUint32(P) is not equal to 232−1.
    var isUInt32 = index >= 0 && index < Math.pow(2, 32) - 1;

    return isInteger && isUInt32 ? index + 1 : prev;
}, 0);

var arr = jQuery.makeArray(obj);
```

Or, let the engine figure it out, using `jQuery.merge()` with an array and the `obj` as [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35692067).

Comment: You could use `Object.keys()` where `.length` is unknown `var obj = { 0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", length: !function() {return Object.keys(this).length }() };`

Comment: What do you mean by _"(Now standardized as Array.from().)"_ ? The `.reduce()` callback is interesting; will have to review `isInteger` and `isUInt32` variables further

Comment: @guest271314 `Array.from()` was defined by ES6 as a native function in JavaScript and has the same behavior as `jQuery.makeArray()`. So, you can perform the same task with or without jQuery in supporting engines.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
_.values({0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"});
```

> ["a", "b", "c"]

Comment: Note that the order of the values isn't guaranteed. Most modern engines do implement with some level of consistency, but the standard doesn't enforce that. So, it's valid if the keys or values shuffle.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - That's true... to guarantee order based on key order: `_.chain({0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"}).pairs().sortBy(([key]) => key).map(([, value]) => value).value();`