# How to convert Object to Array of Objects in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my Code

```
"type":{"0":   
        {   "label":"name",
    "required":false,
    "type":"String",
    },
    "1":
        {   "label":"email",
    "required":false,
    "type":"String",
    }
   }
```

In the above code I have `Type` object which contains two nested objects. Now I want to convert that object to array of objects in the following format using angularjs.

OutPut should be like this:-

```
"type":[
        {   "label":"name",
    "required":false,
    "type":"String",
    },
        {   "label":"email",
    "required":false,
    "type":"String",
    }
   ]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/a-better-way-to-convert-js-object-to-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```js
var arr = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key)
{
    arr.push(obj[key]);
});
obj = { type: arr };
```

Comment: You have missed that the output should be `{ type: [...] }`

Comment: ThankYou @Tom Mettam.Its Working

Answer (score 1):

You could use the keys as index of the array.

```js
var object = { "type": { "0": { "label": "name", "required": false, "type": "String", }, "1": { "label": "email", "required": false, "type": "String", } } },
    array = [];

Object.keys(object.type).map(function (k) {
    array[+k] = object.type[k];
});
object.type = array;
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: You have missed that the output should be `{ type: [...] }`

Answer (score 1):

You should do this using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
objsArray = [];
Object.keys(objs).forEach(function(key)
{
    objsArray.push(objs[key]);
});
```

Comment: You too have missed that the output should be `{ type: [...] }`

Answer (score 0):

say you have

```
var obj = {"type":{"0":   
        {   "label":"name",
    "required":false,
    "type":"String",
    },
    "1":
        {   "label":"email",
    "required":false,
    "type":"String",
    }
   }}
```

you can do

```
var arr = [];
for(var key in obj.type){
  arr.push(obj.type[key])
}
obj.type = arr;
```

Comment: You have missed that the output should be `{ type: [...] }`

Comment: ya, that's why I have written `obj.type = arr;` which will replace old object with array

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your object was:

```
var myObj = "type":{"0":   
        {   "label":"name",
    "required":false,
    "type":"String",
    },
    "1":
        {   "label":"email",
    "required":false,
    "type":"String",
    }
   };
```

If you're using Lodash library:

```
myObj.type = _.map(myObj.type)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of joining the party - better late than never. Working with arrays using functional programming is lots of fun and the accepted answer is great but a slight tweak and you got what is in my opinon much cleaner code.

```
 obj = { type: Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) { return obj[key]; }) };
```

or using a cleaner more sucinct ES6 steez

```
 obj = { type: Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]) };
```

Super clean!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily without loops:

```
// Assuming Problem: 
var objectToArray = 
{
"type":{"0": {"label":"name",
              "required":false,
              "type":"String",
             },
        "1": { "label":"email",
              "required":false,
               "type":"String",
             }
        }
    }

// Answer:
console.log( {type : Array.from(Object.values(objectToArray.type))} );
```

Comment: `Object.values()` returns an array, you don't need to call `Array.from()`