# Converting FirebaseDataSnapshot into a JS object

Tags: firebase, angular

I am `push`ing on object into my `ROOMS` array with `.on("child_added", ....)` as below.  One of the parts of that object is an array of other objects (`Player` obj which has some properties like `id`, `name`, and so on).  How do i assign to `ROOMS.players` because `snap.child("players").val()` does not work (`EXCEPTION: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'`)  `snap.child("players").val()` structure looks something like this:

```
-rooms
   -id
   -name
   -isRoomFull
   +board
   -players
      -kEFvdfeff84fdfdff
          -id
          -name
      -kEFvd4545dfjh9fvv
          -id
          -name



getRooms() {
this.roomsRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
    ROOMS.push({
        id: snap.child("id").val(),
        name: snap.child("name").val(),
        players: [], //how to assign to this property
        isRoomFull: snap.child("isRoomFull").val(),
        board: snap.child("board").val(),
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like that:

```
var obj = snap.child("players").val().players;
var players = Object.keys(obj).map(key => return obj[key]);

ROOMS.push({
    id: snap.child("id").val(),
    name: snap.child("name").val(),
    players: players,
    isRoomFull: snap.child("isRoomFull").val(),
    board: snap.child("board").val(),
});
```

See this question for more details:

- [Converting a JS object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/a-better-way-to-convert-js-object-to-array)

Comment: That worked good.  I had to modify couple things

`var obj = snap.child("players").val();

var players = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {return obj[key]});`