# Converting a JS object to an array -duplicate-

Tags: arrays, object, hash

I know that my question might be questioned before by others.

I am referring to this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array). [Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert) already give the answered correctly. here [Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert) answered:

```
var myObj = {
1: [1, 2, 3],
2: [4, 5, 6]
};

var array = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
  return [value];
});

console.log(array);
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I add 1 line code after output `console.log` which to pass the data to text field

```
$('#assign').val(array);
```

I got the value `array` in my text field like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Is there any way to reformat the data on text field become like this:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

or

```
[{1,2,3},{4,5,6}]
```

Really hope from anyone help! thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to turn your object into a string?
If so, you could do this :

Your object :

```
var myObj = {
1: ["a", "3", "h"],
2: ["r", "y", "s"]
};
```

Turn your object to an array of strings

```
var array = jQuery.map(myObj, function(value) {
  return "[" + value + "]";
});
```

Start your string, fill it with your values

```
var myString = "[";
array.forEach(function(value){myString += value + ","});
```

Then remove the last coma and put in your last bracket :

```
myString = myString.substring(0,myString.length-1) + "]";
```

Now, if you should have your string with the required format

```
alert(myString); //[[a,3,h],[r,y,s]]
```