# Convert a JSON to map using underscore in angular

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I'm new to underscore and I want to convert a json data on my controller that look like this :

```
{ENGLISH: "STOCK", FRENCH: "STOCK", UK: "акції"}
```

to this

```
[{key:"ENGLISH", value:"STOCK"}, {key:"FRENSH", value:"STOCK"}...]
```

Comment: loop over `object` and create a new `object` with `key` and `value` property then push that `object` inside a collection, that's it, refer [Converting a JS object to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6857468/2435473)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var stocks = {ENGLISH: "STOCK", FRENCH: "STOCK", UK: "акції"};

_.map(stocks,function(value, key){ 
    return {
       key:key,
       value:value
    };
});
```

Comment: In the function, the 1st parameter is value and the 2nd parameter is key.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this using only angular also

```
var input = {ENGLISH: "STOCK", FRENCH: "STOCK", UK: "акції"};
var output = [];
angular.forEach(input, function(v, k) {
  this.push({key: k, value: v});
}, output);
```