# Convert an object to an array in angular2/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Am new to angular and typescript and I have this function

```
 onSetValues(user){ //user is an object
    console.log(user);  
 }
```

The console.log above returns an object of the form

```
role:"administrator"
status:10
tries:2
```

I would like to transform thisto an array so that i can loop through them like

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
 //do m stuff here
  }
```

How do i convert this

I have checked on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array)  but it doesnt offere help in angular2/typescript

I have also tried

```
console.log(user| {}) //also fails
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can loop through the properties of your object directly if this would be the only reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an interface with the properties,

```
interface user{
  role: string;
  status: string;
  tries: number;
}
```

Create an array inside the appcomponent,

```
 users: user[] = [];
```

And then you can push the user object and make as a array,

```
this.users.push(user);
```

Comment: sorry that should be this.users

Comment: This now creates an array but its an array of this object but i wantend the values to be pushed to an array, What i mean is this it creates an array of the form ((array(0->the user obect)))  what i was looking for is an array of the form(array(role:"",status:10,...))

Comment: so the push pushes the object to the array but am looking for a way to push the object properties(status,role, tries) and make them an array

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to convert your object values to array... you would have to do this.

```
  let user = {
    role:"administrator",
    status:10,
    tries:2,
  };

  let arr = [];
  for(let key in user){
   if(user.hasOwnProperty(key)){
     arr.push(user[key]);
   }
  }
  console.log(arr);
```

Result from console.log

`0:"administrator"
 1:10
 2:2`

Answer (score 0):

Just put the response `data` inside a `square bracket`.

And save it in the `class`.

```
this.servicename.get_or_post().subscribe(data=> this.objectList = [data]);
```