# Separate object with properties?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like

```
obj = {
   a0: 1,
   b0: 2,
   b1: 3,
   a1: 4
}
```

I want make this object to array as shown

```
obj1 = [
       {a0: 1, b0: 2},
       {a1: 4, b1: 3}
]
```

Group properties that end with same number. Please help me

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array

Answer (score 3):

You could use the number of the key as index and build a new object, if not exist. Then apply the value to the property.

```js
var object = { a0: 1, b1: 3, a1: 4, c2: 5 },
    grouped = Object.keys(object).reduce(function (result, key) {
        var index = key.match(/\d+$/);
        result[index] = result[index] || {};
        result[index][key] = object[key];
        return result;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Can someone please tell me the best answer among these 2?