# Writing object to array in function form

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How would I write the code below in function form?

```
var obj = {
  name : 'Tim',
  age : 20,
  hasPets : false
};
console.log(Object.keys(obj).map(function(item){
    return obj[item];
})); //=> [ 'Tim', 20, false ]
```

For example--this type of function form:

```
 function objectToArray(obj) {
//code here
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't it be called `objToArray`?

Comment: Simply putting your clog code into the arrayToObject function ? What are exactly I/O you expect ?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want object to array (as the title suggests), or array to object (as the example function name you provide suggests)?

Comment: so simple to realize ...

Comment: What you want is this  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array)

Comment: Yes, I meant objectToArray. I just edited it.  Sorry! I'm brand new to coding so it may be simple to you but I'm just learning. :) Thanks so much!

Comment: @Cerbus Are you sure that this is a dupe. OP know how to get values out of object, he is just trying to wrapping that thing in a function. Reopening.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: At least ___close___ it as dupe of something like that then. The question ___is___ a dupe. The target I chose does literally the same. Don't re-open stuff like this. Even if the close reason isn't a "perfect" match, we don't need dozens of answers on simple stuff like wrapping a few lines in a function.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah. Partially agreed. The term 'simple' is subjective. And unless I find the dupe answers the question 100%, I don't mark questions as duplicate.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: The dupe _does_ answer the question. It does literally the same as the OP needs. I didn't get the JS Mjölnir for no reason. Don't re-open a question if it should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```
 function getMappedItems(obj) {
  var result =  Object.keys(obj).map(function(item){
    return obj[item];
  });
 return result;
};
```

Can reduce the above function a bit, but just elaborated as you learning.

https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/be7q88qv/

Comment: How about we at least change the function name to match what it does??

Answer (score 1):

```
 var objectToArray= function (obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).map(function(item){
          return obj[item];
      }); 
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Object.prototype.objectToArray` for a elegant way.

```js
var obj = {
  name : 'Tim',
  age : 20,
  hasPets : false
};

Object.prototype.objectToArray=function(){
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(item){
        return obj[item];
    }); 
};
console.log(obj.objectToArray())
```

Comment: Dude, don't modify `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Cerbrus, Please explain why not ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I just knew that you will downvote me for my opinion xD FYI: I didn't downvote you.

Comment: There's plenty of articles out there, like [this](http://lucybain.com/blog/2014/js-extending-built-in-objects/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice).

Comment: @Kinduser, i don't downvote you.