# read Firebase array to local variable in ionic2

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

In Firebase DB the structure how Array is stored is as follows.

```
// When we send this
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
// Firebase stores this
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}
```

I am reading this data in my Ionic2 project using AngularFire2.
I am getting the whole string as `{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}`.
How to take each value in an Array of string.

Comment: Check answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array avoid the jquery solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a JS object to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array)

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html