# How to convert object to pure array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Convert this:

```
var addresses ={"1":{"A":null,"B":null,"C":null,"D":null,"E":null},"2":{"A":"Resumen por unidades Canal Reatail ","B":null,"C":null,"D":null,"E":null},"3":{"A":"Distribuidores Harina Clementina","B":null,"C":null,"D":null,"E":null},"4":{"A":"Nombre ","B":"Direcci\u00f3n","C":"Tel ","D":"Municipo","E":null},"5":{"A":"Distribuidor Sinaloa","B":"Distribuidor Culiac\u00e1n, Sinaloa ","C":"667 307 2992","D":"Culiac\u00e1n, Sin.","E":null},"6":{"A":"Fruter\u00eda Varela boutique Chapultepec\u00a0","B":"Dr. Manuel Romero #99 local 7 y 8 plaza 99 col Chapultepec","C":"667 712 7036","D":"Culiac\u00e1n, Sin.","E":null},"7":{"A":"Mi tierra","B":"Carlos Lineo 1997, local 101 y 102. Col. Chapultepec.\u00a0","C":"667 712 9884","D":"Culiac\u00e1n, Sin.","E":null},"8":{"A":"Delicity Market Entorno Margarita","B":"Eulogio Parra esq. Aztecas Plaza Entorno Margarita","C":"1812 9124","D":"Guadalajara, Jal ","E":null},"9":{"A":"Adios Gluten ","B":"Av Pablo Neruda 3141, Providencia 4a. Secc","C":"3640 1475","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"10":{"A":"Don Jos\u00e9 Gracian ","B":"Plaza M\u00e9xico - Av. M\u00e9xico 3300 Local 14-D","C":"3444 1906","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"11":{"A":"Don Jos\u00e9 Gracian ","B":"Plaza Tepeyac - Av Patria 1150 Local 50 D","C":"\u00a03620 2189","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"12":{"A":"Don Jos\u00e9 Gracian ","B":"San Juan de Dios - Caba\u00f1as 192 Col. Centro. ","C":"3617 0210\u00a0","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"13":{"A":"Don Jos\u00e9 Gracian ","B":"L\u00f3pez Cotilla - L\u00f3pez cotilla 424 Col Centro","C":"3614 3986","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"14":{"A":"Ecotienda Cuauhtemoc ","B":"Av Cuauht\u00e9moc 3880-DCol. Ciudad del Sol ","C":"\u00a03616 8304","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"15":{"A":"Ecotienda Morelos","B":"Calle Morelos #2178 Col. Ladr\u00f3n de Guevara ","C":"3616 8304","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"16":{"A":"El Mercadito de Mam\u00e1 ","B":"Av. Acueducto 3925, Colinas de San Javier 2da Secci\u00f3n","C":"3611 1305","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"17":{"A":"Healthy Market","B":"Av. Circunvalaci\u00f3n Agust\u00edn Y\u00e1\u00f1ez 2812, Vallarta","C":"3616 3061","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"18":{"A":"La Panza es primero Plaza del Sol","B":"Av. L\u00f3pez Mateos # 2375 Loc. 35 Zona 1 ","C":"3123 1847","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"19":{"A":"La Panza es primero Plaza Independencia","B":"Calz. Independencia # 3259 Local 27 Zona C","C":"3168 0150","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"20":{"A":"La Panza es primero Plaza Sur","B":"Av. Cruz del Sur # 3689 Local 23 Zona D ","C":"3133 9064","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"21":{"A":"La Panza es primero Santa Tere ","B":"Andr\u00e9s Ter\u00e1n #471 Col Santa Teresita. ","C":"3827 3652","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"22":{"A":"Ppanader\u00eda Goiti","B":"Av. M\u00e9xico 2850, Terranova","C":"3642 7512","D":"Guadalajara, Jal. ","E":null},"23":{"A":"La Panza es primero Vallarta Caracol","B":"Plaza Caracol Local 6-1 Zona hotelera norte","C":"322 293 4626","D":"Puerto Vallarta, Jal. ","E":null},"24":{"A":"La Panza es primero Vallarta Pitillal ","B":"Fco. Villa #1542 Loc 32 Col Ex Hda el Pitillal ","C":"322 224 7361","D":"Puerto Vallarta, Jal. ","E":null},"25":{"A":"Don Jos\u00e9 Gracian ","B":"Megacomer - Rafael Sanzio 55 Int Local 5 ","C":"1252 2452","D":"Zapopan, Jal","E":null},"26":{"A":"Fruter\u00eda Marian","B":"Montevideo 2833 Providencia","C":"3331 2123 ","D":"Zapopan, Jal","E":null},"27":{"A":"La Cosecha ","B":"Av. Patria 1861, Puerta de Hierro","C":"3165 2407","D":"Zapopan, Jal","E":null},"28":{"A":"Allimentaci\u00f3n Alternativa","B":"Av. Patria 543 Jard. Guadalupe, Zapopan","C":"3344 8469","D":"Zapopan, Jal.","E":null},"29":{"A":"Amor Org\u00e1nico ","B":"Av de Las Rosas 559, Chapalita Oriente, Chapalita Sur","C":"1983 6946","D":"Zapopan, Jal.","E":null},"30":{"A":"Deli Container","B":"Av.\u00a0Vallarta 6020. Col.  Jocot\u00e1n","C":"1657 2777","D":"Zapopan, Jal.","E":null},"31":{"A":"Hoja Fresca","B":"Av. Inglaterra 6765-13. Col. Villas de Asis.","C":3314105505,"D":"Zapopan, Jal.","E":null},"32":{"A":"La condesa Deli Market","B":"Av. Guadalupe #6818 Local 3. Col. Residencial Guadalupe","C":"2304 0397","D":"Zapopan, Jal.","E":null},"33":{"A":"Semilla Dorada","B":"\u00a0Pino Su\u00e1rez 67, Centro Zapopan","C":"3364 6159","D":"Zapopan, Jal.","E":null},"34":{"A":"Delicity Market Naciones Unidas ","B":"Naciones Unidas #1885","C":"3629 6687","D":"Zapopan, Jal. ","E":null},"35":{"A":"Delicity Market Plaza Palmas","B":"Manuel \u00c1vila Camacho #660-3","C":"3165 4143","D":"Zapopan, Jal. ","E":null},"36":{"A":"La panza es primero Plaza Amistad","B":"Av Patria #600 Entre Bruno Traven y Nac Unidas","C":"3110 6027","D":"Zapopan, Jal. ","E":null},"37":{"A":"La panza es primero Plaza Patria","B":"Av de las Americas #1950 Local 13 Zona D","C":"3641 8580","D":"Zapopan, Jal. ","E":null},"38":{"A":"Oscar Hern\u00e1ndez ","B":"Olmos 121 Col El Mante","C":"33 1456  5561","D":"Zapopan, Jal. ","E":null},"39":{"A":"Purorganiko","B":" Av.L. Van Beethoven 5335, La Estancia","C":"3629 1910","D":"Zapopan, Jal. ","E":null},"40":{"A":"Total unidades Menual","B":null,"C":null,"D":null,"E":null}};
```

to an array

Comment: at least show the desired example output if not your attempts

Comment: please add the wanted result an what you have tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and iterate the keys of the outer object and a given array for the inner keys. Return an array for each inner object in an array for the whole object.

```js
var addresses = { 1: { A: null, B: null, C: null, D: null, E: null }, 2: { A: "Resumen por unidades Canal Reatail ", B: null, C: null, D: null, E: null }, 3: { A: "Distribuidores Harina Clementina", B: null, C: null, D: null, E: null }, 4: { A: "Nombre ", B: "Direcci\\u00f3n", C: "Tel ", D: "Municipo", E: null }, 5: { A: "Distribuidor Sinaloa", B: "Distribuidor Culiac\\u00e1n, Sinaloa ", C: "667 307 2992", D: "Culiac\\u00e1n, Sin.", E: null }, 6: { A: "Fruter\\u00eda Varela boutique Chapultepec\\u00a0", B: "Dr. Manuel Romero #99 local 7 y 8 plaza 99 col Chapultepec", C: "667 712 7036", D: "Culiac\\u00e1n, Sin.", E: null }, 7: { A: "Mi tierra", B: "Carlos Lineo 1997, local 101 y 102. Col. Chapultepec.\\u00a0", C: "667 712 9884", D: "Culiac\\u00e1n, Sin.", E: null } },
    result = Object.keys(addresses).map(function (k) {
        return ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'].map(function (l) {
            return addresses[k][l];
        })
    });

    console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should make the trick via jQuery

```
var arr = $.map(addresses, function(el) { return el });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n6dasygx/