# Javascript convert nested objects in array to arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a nested array, but I've got a array with nested objects.

What i have:

```
[
    { id: 1, title: 'title', value: 'test data'}
    { id: 2, title: 'title', value: 'test data'}
]
```

But i need:

```
[
    [ 1, 'title', 'test data']
    [ 2, 'title', 'test data']
]
```

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors. Put the quotes at the right places.

Comment: What did you try to accomplish this? Did you use `for` statement or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a JS object to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array)

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Answer (score 6):

You can perform a `.map(x => Object.values(x))` on it.

Live example:

```js
let src = [
    { id: 1, title: 'title', value: 'test data'},
    { id: 2, title: 'title', value: 'test data'}
];

let result = src.map(x => Object.values(x));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are filled with creativity as always.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) direct as callback.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, title: 'title', value: 'test data' }, { id: 2, title: 'title', value: 'test data'}],
    result = data.map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

using `forEach` loop:

```js
var obj = [
    { id: 1, title: 'title', value: 'test data'},
    { id: 2, title: 'title', value: 'test data'}
];

var arr = [];

obj.forEach(function(o, k) {
 arr.push([o.id, o.title, o.value]);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try like this using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) and [**`object.values()`**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFxY6wnLXTAhXDQo8KHWHGAokQFgglMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_objects%2FObject%2Fvalues&usg=AFQjCNE5UlL1cEh99fUgeunohGICKbz8Ew&sig2=YPd33EV2SMSLGFoPjtwUng).and your code have some `syntax error` missing `'`and `,`

```js
var a = [{  id: 1,  title: 'title',  value: 'test data',}, {  id: 2,  title: 'title',  value: 'testdata',}];
var n = a.map(a=>Object.values(a))
console.log(n)
```

Comment: I think we have just a little different view about 'readable code'. Here is your code that might look like https://jsfiddle.net/w4d8yw35/
Try to avoid inline code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [**Array.proptotype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) method along with [**Object.values()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to loop your array and return the wanted result:

```
var results = data.map(function(item) {
  var elem = [];
  elem.push(Object.values(item));
  return elem;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'title',
    value: 'test data'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'title',
    value: 'test data'
  }
];

var results = data.map(function(item) {
  var elem = [];
  elem.push(Object.values(item));
  return elem;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```