# Ajax to .NET Can't bind multiple parameters error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

When I try to pass values with ajax like this:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "PUT",
     dataType: 'json',
     url: "http://localhost:52930/api/person/",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: {persoon1, persoon2, file}
 })
     .done(function( msg ) {
         alert("Test")
     });
```

In which person1 and 2 is an object, and a file is a byte array (JSON).

Using this function in .NET

```
    public IHttpActionResult Put(Person personFrom , Person personTo , byte[] file)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        _personRepository.EncrypFileAndSendToPerson(file, personFrom  , personTo);
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Person", id = personTo.Id }, personTo);
    }
```

And this is the person class:

```
public class Person
{
    private RSAWithRSAParameterKey _rsaParameters;
    public Person()
    {
        _rsaParameters = new RSAWithRSAParameterKey();
        _rsaParameters.AssignNewKey();
        PrivateKey = _rsaParameters._privateKey;
        PublicKey = _rsaParameters._publicKey;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
    public string PrivateKey { get; set; }
    public string PublicKey { get; set; }
    public EncryptedPacket Packet { get; set; }       
}
```

Why do I keep getting this error and how do I fix it?

Full error

```
{Message: "An error has occurred.",…}
ExceptionMessage
:
"Can't bind multiple parameters ('personFrom' and 'file') to the request's content."
ExceptionType
:
"System.InvalidOperationException"
Message
:
"An error has occurred."
StackTrace
:
"   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

EDIT:

This is the data I am getting when I console.log() the values in `data`

```
{"personFrom":{"Id":2,"Name":"Sinan","Password":"wachtwoord2","Salt":"22ad8a4c-3175-4049-a9e0-f4f383c1cd09","File":null,"PrivateKey":"<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>3A86Zo99HaROAME/yU7POcogo4Zru62F+7PAXONv3Jm8l2RMfb4QlcCF483kXV85paVpbgI7en3O5eiFoTEUVUXP9InjpNg7X9jah8tJFLRvzIU74vHP7ccLXgOV5ztGUEGW2ESbpT6gkvNS6XvMyMS+r8rQt1mvNp3lhAErK81a6Pr1npVmew9cghikY5NOk5WcaAeh8pB4hPeGbTg33BRzEN+w8IeJh73EwKDz8fKklqbFv90qRUPciKKUStyCxTCU4yg43de4qcuzNXMXqjFF8NY0JXu+6L6yuRvrdFoBN4OWe2GLEGxVoemDWvO7rwP9qkSq51Bk9CnW4bd98w==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>9dfUtHHiLbySstMMquL0QTazj8AI/S2IBpJX9kXgRQ9SaJ3l6VlbMmSTvjY3MgRK6OF3MISMlBRqAa0ptxttXyh1fEvS7B44XVrOOREEQQkRBo5Ly02vXFYudBApgd68EijBDcI0l3v7CzQu6Ng/ROLAYnrd4K9AzZ+cppRZ6tE=</P><Q>5SayKSK/R6I944RMeA/DYfep/KXiePSyE/MyI2A72q2bG8MaLG8w1JN1p5T5tfB2Tgyn/ePHjVoP7CYoRQz6PIcyxDDqRzyw5tDpQ0Rc3lTcJkM1WmWyB+9NDIV1mmhDgyUWAssS0IhKg/6HOat2dBbEPE+d9qgi9tjfQetKRYM=</Q><DP>9FLnxd1Yl3PNp4MwF7UuYpFmqvqC9HsHsOBIIy0W0guELwydredsRwzF+EgRWtgBSqiot8NDovcW00uxJZVQgT3IZRtGJ/twsPbJ9NUAkVHdZdKNaSNvoCjWSeq2Faey6akvE+lqMxK4UE4wQKCJYICqCjVpxR7nHHQAT10ob8E=</DP><DQ>RXjm2LvVHAWfF8Q7XscAqEnqulMchylAd/XqRHlfjBvIA7Gx1LjdKAWQzP7IehVt+JmzsLCHBl7ApwqmeNDHaORgSsS9sl0/EKtTnPYz5Z/6oosLuN1ODUPKqzom/moP1cm/k5c3nAtF9CCNpLlMD0P7uIE21doBx67WeOi5urs=</DQ><InverseQ>R8GMrONl4TchpuUPv3DxfbqEAqGH5zhgOtPuvLLMfGXXCo0xWJpFDK7k7x6qt5oMjMnqhoqW/VAx3quOkO79cHdcDRoMGjAjuSNj+dQ+dH/qyAf18qsq0mmHxpsB3LUpe3TLDvRQETqTemuc6hmGo4kNLeV7w9aab3PuJxpduWI=</InverseQ><D>PqoteMA6okLEHa3qQqKpGy1GfxqLuj2PLl6BFFKF671xuXDL4XDK20IgPn9GnRo9WcDRVYzYMCj8TncY+o512lSPg/TyOOKEgeZIUKwgav946LY2GAnBKtZoE8UUnmzAOKF82agr5HIBmuckgK2K4s839+pa5iNpZDWxgpYsm4OPMQ4PPGJVkjQEDW9MZn1/gMrmsBsilOjLSq338Hk9Gz3kcXvM/KVACDkWY3EdUOQO9JNsEvbIaBXH3qUNNZ6xoW2ZjzLBtoe975tFByjG2rz3pHb9rpt3nQ9JC1cCzkj1+uxwlR2nRlISZt8sIA8eCV40f6h6Kn15M88TV6VkkQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>","PublicKey":"<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>3A86Zo99HaROAME/yU7POcogo4Zru62F+7PAXONv3Jm8l2RMfb4QlcCF483kXV85paVpbgI7en3O5eiFoTEUVUXP9InjpNg7X9jah8tJFLRvzIU74vHP7ccLXgOV5ztGUEGW2ESbpT6gkvNS6XvMyMS+r8rQt1mvNp3lhAErK81a6Pr1npVmew9cghikY5NOk5WcaAeh8pB4hPeGbTg33BRzEN+w8IeJh73EwKDz8fKklqbFv90qRUPciKKUStyCxTCU4yg43de4qcuzNXMXqjFF8NY0JXu+6L6yuRvrdFoBN4OWe2GLEGxVoemDWvO7rwP9qkSq51Bk9CnW4bd98w==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>","Packet":null},"personTo":{"Id":3,"Name":"Lennert","Password":"wachtwoord3","Salt":"daa4ccff-5764-41eb-b151-8b3cbc0f870b","File":null,"PrivateKey":"<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>44KWMkW7KFrnaK4qD90VSfiwLdttfpOYK+pApqXSAg2NnFLGxvI7AHoOWwQEQiYtQwyDjkNuxWsWxhYeMV9XwNaoba6hH/4iFx4ZR68FCJD5KsSfPuk+X4cf/R5auMKvLboKOFz9yRFYnBN17uQyI8NPhjTaAIRPJ5eTr/H+D6ug9hnwtz7tc/vpBPyjyomTcnUa9GVOrYAQ0RtsAvTJ2of9mT3G67WUhzIMqKsAFP6mObyAcyFgQx0uFdVFSFCOw26a0ASZM3juEVDT4OSWIZz3tWLD2acSPJTNxJFyvUMeEyc4dLPnPgZF/VypIjnuu4CZ/pplqS6N5Z3QhWgS2Q==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>+Kk3iG6f03CG8yPWvN0CfkpHpVq2yvSguujscE6ZGW57cPYP3J02quqGvnCT5UUNxiyZt1tu/xh4HcapT2HVN1H4kCZdsKdbovGvjdAHzgZdNXunpLzIwvCbp9wskOqGClyZXKO1kEFhQ+u+69PuH9ifE8yxvzanfLc5irNY908=</P><Q>6jmP4ikBIawVTk5DVKKbvw9tkN0GdbTzMU7wTYHYoh61/k438AoOcnngr96orbqSQNtFucQ5IRonkHDqjjZrPlCYh+VpGCKR4Vl3+TWBc/ad1xiBRcmgfGyd72CRqYU3sjsfNe1zYkgvJqpUf0frafUz2tqBR+Bk/jC/RAhRyVc=</Q><DP>Ch6AxwmRcX5Tz5M2yurHjjIhpkYByFKaM+EEtjFMo69OULOCw7yWG/B9WUSlkB/2RolMHB0ZcEIjqTqLa1KU5bJtRhh5mZXF8eSZ+1Bq8ORraKDGmrqgBObbvsIEAkW4/LT1/MIgwmUWuzfdxiUSvLMJDjo3RYvI1xdxvQY9aZs=</DP><DQ>MbpK2/9MqDN6yoc/MEbdvjCuWGU0q+ThBQT3a903eyP+C6HbqnDYJGHP3EbvlQLZbj+fjBMm9eoxoC74/Xx8RFykJaYFLASa6Dcwi45aj546YKJpP8HQ+tmsplfgVRddfc+jjrV9G86rhBABpIxGZNaUTdC6ReJUTstWsED77D0=</DQ><InverseQ>pQnuS/ovatWINEwmdZBRfyjUtDesiYrMFF45RtInMaoXe0aNQFuWqIuBejleuijSESk6rFwurmg/GpB2fZJ2yRfxp5VYfQqnJjXDIMjEc2aphvc82e4TM7JGJrmeyhOsjjTA0whW6ua/d9rH/baFy02o0qI739vvBamL95GZvL0=</InverseQ><D>Prz9nzpkfKHoy5Cvr7U3UDFAoDyw6qVX4tBT6MC0c3V6Vh/rieQ1ihGekNHAPN+bPrCePKZyzwUTgCeMRvA0Wky3oJt1+kUR8I8PyJlGiZC07WrQQUB/v0cbdqkeunGRbkot1FIsd/yNE2k4bdrGyt7quKctcNQLoe7mPrA8b+ROsrRgoSpmV+3cX6CUWA2ireuI789mIgXGJ+5Fik9iq8gRMvOsAqCC8fivBxlxAmIYA1+jANFgbcu17bvalI4z58C99VDYfqp/zjIIbDs4rmtqVDzIJfDYDFjyZi1EivgbpDakj2V7yqHvkYF8lbSSUIrCQ7WROjokQ4bzwcav+w==</D></RSAKeyValue>","PublicKey":"<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>44KWMkW7KFrnaK4qD90VSfiwLdttfpOYK+pApqXSAg2NnFLGxvI7AHoOWwQEQiYtQwyDjkNuxWsWxhYeMV9XwNaoba6hH/4iFx4ZR68FCJD5KsSfPuk+X4cf/R5auMKvLboKOFz9yRFYnBN17uQyI8NPhjTaAIRPJ5eTr/H+D6ug9hnwtz7tc/vpBPyjyomTcnUa9GVOrYAQ0RtsAvTJ2of9mT3G67WUhzIMqKsAFP6mObyAcyFgQx0uFdVFSFCOw26a0ASZM3juEVDT4OSWIZz3tWLD2acSPJTNxJFyvUMeEyc4dLPnPgZF/VypIjnuu4CZ/pplqS6N5Z3QhWgS2Q==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>","Packet":null},"file":"{\"1\":115,\"2\":100,\"3\":100,\"4\":115,\"5\":100,\"6\":97}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this happens because parameters are not optional and you don't apply `FromBody` attribute to parameters. Try this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(
    [FromBody] Person personFrom,
    [FromBody] Person personTo,
    [FromBody] byte[] file)
{
    ...
}
```

If it didn't help try to create new model to map request to that will contain all properties:

```
public class PutModel
{
    public Person PersonFrom {get; set;}
    public Person PersonTo {get; set;}
    public byte[] File {get; set;}
}
```

And define single parameter in your action:

```
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody] PutModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

And make sure that property names are correct as @Jay suggested.

```
data: {
    "personFrom": persoon1,
    "personTo": persoon2,
    "file": file
}
```

Also, based on the message in the console, file is an object, not an array in JS. Try explicitly make it an array like in [Converting a JS object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array):

```
var array = $.map(file, function(value, index) {
    return value;
});
```

Comment: It's giving 400 bad request now.

Comment: [[123], [34], [49], [34], [58], [49], [49], [53], [44], [34], [50], [34], [58], [49], [48], [48], [44],…] That's how the array looks now

Comment: @SinanSamet, Array does not look right, should be without inner arrays with one value. Just simple array.
400 is because you `return BadRequest();` I suppose.

Comment: Is it because of the array?

Comment: Could be, I don't know how you validate it. I would say yes. Try to debug or check what bad request message in body says.

Comment: @SinanSamet, I have updated my answer to map object to array without inner arrays.

Comment: This solved the problem! The array was causing the 400 error. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Pass Value like this way

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://localhost:52930/api/person/",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {
        "personFrom": persoon1,
        "personTo": persoon2,
        "file": file
    }
})
        .done(function (msg) {
            alert("Test")
        });
```

Comment: I editted my question to contain the exact data I am sending

Comment: Can you please change **byte[]**  file to **string file** just for try

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    url: 'http://localhost:52930/api/person/',
                    dataType: 'application/json',
                    data: {
                         personFrom : persoon1, 
                         personTo : persoon2,
                         file: file                       
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Application Updated Successfully");
                    },
                    error: function (err) { 
                    }
                });
```

you suppose to populate objects in javascript like:

```
var persoon1 = {
Id: $("#id").val(),
Name: $("#Name").val(),
}
```

you method be like:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))] //whatever the response
public IHttpActionResult Put(Person personFrom , Person personTo , byte[] file)
    {
    }
```