# Node.js How To Parse String IN Array-JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, parsing

```
var Download = request.download; // a["{\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":\"no\"}"] // String
```

How can parse this string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: `var a = a["{\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":\"no\"}"]` is invalid JavaScript. Declaring `var a` in the same statement where you're trying to access a key which is JSON (which makes no sense), will throw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '{"status":"success","data":"no"}' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you are trying to do here, but I will assume that you want to parse the string into an object:

```
var string = "{\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":\"no\"}";
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

If you really want an array, you can look this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array) to convert you're object into an array.

Answer (score -1):

To parse that string just use JSON.parse().  Run a js console and try this

```
JSON.parse("{\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":\"no\"}");
```

That will return a js object.