# How to convert key-value pair object into an array of values in ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, keyvaluepair

I'm developing a React application where I need to convert a key-value object like this:

```
{
  0: 'John',
  1: 'Tim',
  2: 'Matt'
};
```

To an array of just the values like this:

```
['John', 'Tim', 'Matt']
```

How do I accomplish this?

```
const obj = {
  0: 'John',
  1: 'Tim',
  2: 'Matt'
};

const arr = /* ??? */;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a JS object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26166303/1896903 This might help you getting your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of `Object.values` command.

According to the **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)**.

> `Object.values()` returns an array whose elements are the enumerable
>   property values found on the object. The ordering of the properties is
>   the same as that given by looping over the property values of the
>   object manually

Although it is an `ES2017` solution but since you are using react, you can include `stage-0` as a preset for `babel` and access this functionality

```js
var data ={
  0: 'John',
  1: 'Tim',
  2: 'Matt'
};

var newdata = Object.values(data);
console.log(newdata);
```

there are other methods like **[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** which gives you all the keys as an array and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property `[key, value]` pairs which might also be useful to you

Comment: Great solution, but it's an ES2017 feature and not supported by older browsers.

Comment: @D.Simon you are right, however since OP is using react, he can make use of stage-0 preset to use it

Comment: @D.Simon So is `const`. As for Object methods, there are polyfills!

Answer (score 12):

You could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

> The **`Object.values()`** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```js
var object = { 0: 'John', 1: 'Tim', 2: 'Matt' }, 
    array = Object.values(object);
    
console.log(array);
```

With ES6, you could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and use a callback for the values.

```js
var object = { 0: 'John', 1: 'Tim', 2: 'Matt' }, 
    array = Array.from(Object.keys(object), k => object[k]);
    
console.log(array);
```

Comment: `Object.values` is not in ES6 included, coming with ES7. He wants something in ES6.

Answer (score 4):

```
const obj = {
  0: 'John',
  1: 'Tim',
  2: 'Matt'
};

const arr = [];
for(let key in obj){
  arr.push(obj[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you have numerical keys and in an order without gaps, you could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with an array as target and the given object as source.

```js
var object = { 0: 'John', 1: 'Tim', 2: 'Matt' }, 
    array = Object.assign([], object);
    
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly used one:

```
const obj={
           1:'Azamat',
           2: 'Kanybek',
           3: 'Manas'}

console.log(Object.values(obj))
```

for key, value pairs:

```
const arr = [];

for(let key in obj){
  arr.push([key,obj[key]])
  
}
console.log(arr)
```