# React convert props Objects into array then setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to convert this props:

[image]

into this array:

```
this.setState({
            locations: [
                { label: 'California', value: 'california' },
                { label: 'Nevada', value: 'nevada' },
            ]
});
```

originally i was using this [plugin](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/) and wanted to replace its default values with my props but cant convert it.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all properties values of a Javascript Object (without knowing the keys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert key-value pair object into an array of values in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411208/how-to-convert-key-value-pair-object-into-an-array-of-values-in-es6)

Comment: Isn't a lodash _.toArray going to work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your flavor of JavaScript and preference of writing

Taking advantage of the `for .. in` operator, which comes with draw backs.
It'll loop over *all* enumerable properties even the ones from the prototype.

```
var arr = [];
for (var key in myObject) {
  arr.push(myObject[key]);
}
```

or by using the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method

```
var arr2 = Object.keys(myObject).map(function (i) {
  return myObject[i];
});
```

or lastly, if you're running an Babel transpiled app, [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```
var arr3 = Object.values(myObject);
```