# How to convert JSON to Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to convert JSON to Array and I return value by :
**console.log(data);**

value is :

```js
[{ "data" : [  [object]  ] },
[{ "data" : [  [object] , [object]  ] }
```

so, I converted to JSON by:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, "    "));
```

value is :

```js
[
  {
    "data" : [
          {
            "month" : 1,
             "name" : "Alex",
             "sum" : 20
          }
      ]  
  },
  {
    "data" : [
          {
            "month" : 2,
             "name" : "Zara",
             "sum" : 18
          },
          {
            "month" : 2,
            "name" : "Zara",
            "sum" : 19
          }
      ]  
  }

]
```

I want convert to Array :

```js
{
  "data" : { [ 1, "Alex", 20 ]  }
},
{
  "data" : { [ 2, "Zara", 18 ]  },
           { [ 2, "Zara", 19 ]  }
}
```

How to convert ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a JS object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array)

Comment: Your expected `JSON` is invalid.

Comment: `"data" :{ [ 1, "Alex", 20 ]  }` - this looks like bad syntax, you probably need to learn basics first. you probably need `data: [ 1, "Alex", 20 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your expected output is incorrect as you cant have object without key value pair.

**you can have your output as**

```
{
  "data" : [ [ 1, "Alex", 20 ]  ]
},
{
  "data" : [[ 2, "Zara", 18 ]  ,
           [ 2, "Zara", 19 ]  ]
}
```

**here is the solution considering above output**

```js
var inputArr = [
  {
    "data" : [
          {
            "month" : 1,
             "name" : "Alex",
             "sum" : 20
          }
      ]  
  },
  {
    "data" : [
          {
            "month" : 2,
             "name" : "Zara",
             "sum" : 18
          },
          {
            "month" : 2,
            "name" : "Zara",
            "sum" : 19
          }
      ]  
  }
];

inputArr.forEach(function(item){
    for (var i=0; i< item.data.length; i++){
        var myArr = [];
        myArr.push(item.data[i].month);
        myArr.push(item.data[i].name);
        myArr.push(item.data[i].sum);
        item.data[i] = myArr;
    }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(inputArr));
```

NOTE: Solution can be simplified if you are Ok to use ES6 in your code.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply try on followings:

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return obj[k] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution (with `jQuery`) https://jsfiddle.net/mhhqj1nc/

```js
var data = [
  {
    "data" : [
          {
            "month" : 1,
             "name" : "Alex",
             "sum" : 20
          }
      ]  
  },
  {
    "data" : [
          {
            "month" : 2,
             "name" : "Zara",
             "sum" : 18
          },
          {
            "month" : 2,
            "name" : "Zara",
            "sum" : 19
          }
      ]  
  }];

var newdata = [];

$.each(data, function(i, v){
  newdata.push({data: []});
  var temp = [];
  $.each(v.data, function(k, val){
    var keys = Object.keys(v.data[k]);
    $.each(keys, function(j){
      temp.push(v.data[k][keys[j]]);
    });
    newdata[i].data.push(temp);
    temp = [];
  });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(newdata));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your **expected output** is **invalid**.

**Expected output** should be

```
[{
  "data": [1, "Alex", 20]
 }, {
  "data": [
    [2, "Zara", 18],
    [2, "Zara", 19]
  ]
}]
```

Here you go with a solution (with vanilla `JavaScript`) https://jsfiddle.net/mhhqj1nc/1/

```js
var data = [
  {
    "data" : [
          {
            "month" : 1,
             "name" : "Alex",
             "sum" : 20
          }
      ]  
  },
  {
    "data" : [
          {
            "month" : 2,
             "name" : "Zara",
             "sum" : 18
          },
          {
            "month" : 2,
            "name" : "Zara",
            "sum" : 19
          }
      ]  
  }];

var newdata = [];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  newdata.push({data: []});
  for(var j=0; j<data[i].data.length; j++){
    var keys = Object.keys(data[i].data[j]);
    var temp = [];
    for(var k in keys){
      temp.push(data[i].data[j][keys[k]]);
    }
    newdata[i].data.push(temp);
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(newdata));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for you answer but I try in filename.js it's return $ is not defined. I wrong ?

Comment: @jane You forgot to add `jQuery` library file. Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the head section

Comment: I use node.js and I try var jquery = require('jquery');  it's return $ is not defined again.

Comment: help me again , please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952057/how-to-convert-data-table-to-json-in-javascript