# How to convert Data table to Json in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I want to convert data table to Json. I use node.js
I have Data Table as :

```
 -------------------------------------
 |   Month    |    Name    |   Sum   |
 -------------------------------------
 |   January  |    John    |   25    |
 |   February |    Jane    |   30    |
 |   February |    John    |   35    |
 |   February |    Alex    |   20    |
 |   March    |    Jane    |   32    |
 |   March    |    John    |   35    |
 |   March    |    Alex    |   30    |
```

I want convert data to Json :

```js
var data = [{
            "Month": "January",
            "Information": [{
              "Name": "John",
              "Sum": 25
            }]
          }, {
            "Month": "February",
            "Information": [{
              "Name": "Jane",
              "Sum": 30
            }, {
              "Name": "John",
              "Sum": 35
            }, {
              "Name": "Alex",
              "Sum": 20
            }]
          },{
            "Month": "March",
            "Information": [{
              "Name": "Jane",
              "Sum": 32
           }, {
              "Name": "John",
              "Sum": 35
           }, {
              "Name": "Alex",
              "Sum": 30
            }]
        }]
```

How to do this.
I want Json to create stacked bar chart.js.
thanks.

Comment: I use postgresql .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/mou882tw/

```js
var data = [];
var lastMonth = "";

var child = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var temp = {};
var th = child[0].children;
for(var i=1; i<child.length; i++){
  var td = child[i].children;
  if(lastMonth != td[0].textContent){
   if( JSON.stringify(temp) != '{}')
    data.push(temp);
   temp = {};
   temp["Information"] = [];
  }

  var innerJSON = {};
  for(var j=0; j<td.length; j++){
   if(j == 0){
     temp[th[j].textContent] = td[j].textContent;
      lastMonth = td[j].textContent;
    } else {
     innerJSON[th[j].textContent] = td[j].textContent;
    }
  }
  temp["Information"].push(innerJSON);
  if(i == (child.length -1)){
   data.push(temp);
  }
}
console.log(data);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>Alex</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>Alex</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Jane.. Hope the answer will help you.

Comment: thanks for you answer but I wrong communication the topic to you . Data table mean Database table . I'm sorry very much, Bother you again, please.

Comment: @Jane please share `database` data, will convert it to proper `JSON` format.

Comment: database data it's same data table on top.

Comment: I mean, it should be in certain format, may be csv, text or some other format.

Answer (score 0):

Any possibility of table to json but with nested json. How it will be formated