# How to turn json to array without using key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects

```
[{
    "A": "thisA",
    "B": "thisB",
    "C": "thisC"
}, {
    "A": "thatA",
    "B": "thatB",
    "C": "thatC"
}]
```

I'm trying to get this format as an end result: `[["thisA","thisB","thisC"], ["thatA","thisB","thatC"]]`

I know we can use map() function with the specific key(A, B, C).

```
newarray = array.map(d => [d['A'], d['B'], d['C']])
```

But I need a common function to transfer it without using the key, because the content of array will be different, the key will be different. Is there any good solution?

Comment: Please post what you have tried?

Comment: `arrayOfObjects.map(Object.values)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON to Array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930723/how-to-convert-json-to-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{
  "A": "thisA",
  "B": "thisB",
  "C": "thisC"
}, {
  "A": "thatA",
  "B": "thatB",
  "C": "thatC"
}]

const result = arr.map(Object.values)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: amazing, I really do not know there is a such method. great thx!

Comment: you may find `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` interesting too. @lan

Answer (score 0):

I've upvoted punksta for elegant solution, but this is how I would do that in automatic mode (without thinking how to make it elegant):

```js
const src = [{
    "A": "thisA",
    "B": "thisB",
    "C": "thisC"
}, {
    "A": "thatA",
    "B": "thatB",
    "C": "thatC"
}]

const result = src.map(o => Object.keys(o).map(k => o[k]))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say the other answer is _to make it elegant_, I'll say _efficient_, and even more readable than this.

Comment: @LGSon You are not wrong. I added my answer just because I wanted to. Because of reasons. And for comparison also, maybe.