# Is possible to re-sort or edit my firebase list in ionic 2?

Tags: list, sorting, firebase, ionic2, edit

I'm not sure if there is any example for my question or not but I want to re-sort or edit my firebase list by using any possible methods.

for example: I have this firebase list:

```
public classesList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
...
this.classesList = this.afd.list('/classes/',{
  query:{
    orderByChild:'uemail',
    equalTo: 'user1@gmail.com'
  }
})
```

And this is a sample example of contains of classesList

```
classesList
-- class1
----- day: 'sun,tus,thu' 
----- time: '10:00'
-- class2
----- day: 'sun,thu'
----- time: '8:00'
-- class3
----- day: 'sun,thu'
----- time: '9:00'
```

My problem: how can make "if statements" between the classes to re-sort my list or push the values in other temp array to use it in my html (& should I add 'async' for the temp array or not ?) !

Comment: Your result from firebase is a JSON. So just use function to modify that JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the `uemail` child in your classesList  example? 
The output of `this.afd.list` is an object. of children matching the query. You can use a function that [converts an object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array), and then [sort the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the way you want.