# JavaScript sort by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, object

How to sort by key "name"? (in alphabetical order)

[image: a busy cat]

It is not working:

```
views.sort(function(a, b) {
  var x = a.name.toLowerCase(),
      y = b.name.toLowerCase();
  return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
})
```

Please help me.

Comment: Define "not working". Be specific about what you expect vs what it's giving you. And does `sort` return the sorted list or modify it in place? I can't remember.

Comment: If that is a log of your `views` variable, that isn't an array, it's a regular object. It won't have a `sort()` function, nor can you sort an object's properties

Comment: @Carcigenicate My code does not the sorting. It just doesn't work. I think all right, but it's not working.

Comment: Your sort function is correct, The problem is somewhere else, please give more code about your objects you're sorting.

Comment: can you post sample array, i think you are not getting array name

Comment: How does `views.sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase())` not work?

Comment: @nikunjMnage it is not array. It is object http://take.ms/9Y73o

Comment: It's going to take me a while to sort an image, be much easier if was in JSON, or a javascript object literal / array..

Comment: @Keith I did it myself Object.values(views)
        .sort(function(a, b) {
            var x = a.name,
                        y = b.name;
           return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
       })

Comment: Crikey!, you have created an algorithm to sort an image,. in such short lines.   And I thought you might need some complicated OCR, as the fist part to extract the text out of the image.  Well I never..!!!

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 0):

You an use `localeCompare` for comparing strings:

```js
var views = {
  viewA: { name: 'Build Plus' },
  viewB: { name: 'Columns' },
  viewC: { name: 'PowerPack Templates', other: 'field' },
  viewD: { name: 'Blog Posts' }
};

var viewsArr = Object.keys(views).map(function (key) { return views[key]; });

viewsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
      var x = a.name.toLowerCase(),
          y = b.name.toLowerCase();
      return x.localeCompare(y);
    })
    
console.log(viewsArr);
```

Update: You are receiving object with keys and values. You need to take values in the array first and then sort them.

See [Converting a JS object to an array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array-using-jquery)

In your case it will be:

```
var viewsArr = Object.keys(views).map(function (key) { return views[key]; });
// sort then
```

Comment: That should work, I put example of your data in the code snippet - take a look

Comment: Oh, I know. you cannot sort them because you have an object with keys which cannot be sorted. You need to convert it first in array.

Comment: @user3608884 actually, it looks weird: on the screenshot you've posted you have collection but then each item in collection has a key (like object). Can you post what is your object/collection look like?

Comment: thanks, but my solution: `var views_new = {};
   Object.values(views)
        .sort(function(a, b) {
            var x = a.name,
                        y = b.name;
           return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
       }).forEach(function(v, i) {
      views_new[v.handle] = v;
         });`

Comment: Glad you was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code that you shared is totally OK, here is the working example:

```js
var arr = [
  {name: 'b'},
  {name: 'a'},
  {name: 'x'},
  {name: 'i'},
  {name: 'l'}
]

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
 var x = a.name.toLowerCase(),
     y = b.name.toLowerCase();
 return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
});

console.log(arr)
```

For more info about `sort`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

May be the issue is somewhere else, in code, which you didn't share.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, yes, I just added working example, which the OP can look through and see, how it's written

Comment: That doesn't help teach OP or other users what is wrong and what was needed to fix the issue.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, OP's code is totally OK, may be the issue is somewhere else, in code, which OP didn't share.

Comment: Correct... so your answer doesn't answer anything... which is my point

Comment: @PatrickEvans, I wrote my answer based on OP's shared code, and said, that His/Her shared code is totally OK, and the issue may be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes meaning you should have just made a comment about that on the question. This answer provides nothing for OP or future users

Comment: @PatrickEvans, the main goal of my answer is to show, that shared by OP code is working with my data

Comment: @user3608884, where the issue was?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide my solution: `var views_new = {}; Object.values(views) .sort(function(a, b) { var x = a.name, y = b.name; return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0)); }).forEach(function(v, i) { views_new[v.handle] = v; });`

Comment: @user3608884, nice to hear, that you founded solution!

Answer (score 0):

Get object values in an array and sort.

```
const viewsArr = Object.values(views)
             .sort((a, b) => a.name.lowerCase() > b.name.lowerCase());
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not exact code but in your you are not getting groups..

```
 let groups = Object.keys(data)
    .map(group => {
let records = Object.values(data[group])
        .map(record => ({
          name: record.name,
          group,
        }));
      return records;
    });
groups = [].concat(...groups);
  return groups.sort((a, b) => {
   return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```

Comment: variables can be declared in a list, ie  `var a=3,b=4,c=4;` which is what OP is doing, they just put the second declaration on a different line