# $.parseJSON(data).shift is not a function

Tags: php, json

i have to parsing json data get from $post method

```
$.post( "vehicle_route_qry.php",function(data) {  

    siteshistory = $.parseJSON(data);
    siteshistory.shift();
    draw_route(siteshistory);
    $("#dev_det_spin").hide();

});
```

my php file

```
$myJSON = '{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }';
echo json_encode($myJSON);
```

i am getting json properly in my response 
but getting this issue

```
siteshistory.shift is not a function
```

i have loaded following js files

```
<script src="js/function.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDaL0ieAkLhzy1rDoLifajeowdXPwTvzmI"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/date.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/header_function.js"></script>
```

but shift function for  $.parseJSON(data).shift() is not working 
i am not able to find any reference regarding shift function

suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Your JSON is not an array ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift
```

Your json should be an array, should not be an object to execute **`shift()`**.

You can refer this question to translate object to array in JS :

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array-using-jquery`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
`"delete siteshistory.name"`;
```

instead of

```
"siteshistory.shift()";
```

Answer (score 0):

//what your trying to `shift()` is not an array
 try below code

```
 var siteshistory = [];

    siteshistoryObj = $.parseJSON('{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }');//add here your ajax response

   //converting to array
    $.each(siteshistoryObj, function (index, order) {
      siteshistory.push({index : index});
    });
    siteshistory.shift();

console.log(siteshistory);// check array values
```