# React map on object then array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

This is my object and I want to map this in my component but I have problem, I cant use map on this object. First value is vote and next is array of users. How I cna use map on this in babel ?

```
  var ObjVote = {
        '1':['EwaK','Jacek','Jacek'],
        '2':['Anna','Pawel','EwaK'],
        '3':['Anna','EwaK','Jacek'],
        '4':['Jas','Jas','Pawel'],
        '5':['Anna','Jas','Pawel']
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Object.keys(ObjVote)
         .map(vote => ({ vote: vote, voters: ObjVote[vote]}))
         .map(data => <Vote {...data} key={data.vote} />)
```

Or

```
Object.keys(ObjVote)
         .map(vote => ({ vote: vote, voters: ObjVote[vote]}))
         .map(data => <Vote data={data} key={data.vote} />)
```

Now inside `Vote` component you can access votes by `props.data.votes` and voters array by `props.data.voters`.

Comment: Unexpected token, expected ; voters: ObjVote[vote]}, after voters

Comment: @PawełBaca put the braces around `{}` in first map, like this: `({ vote: vote, voters: ObjVote[vote]})`, it will work.

Comment: `Object.keys(ObjVote)
               .map(vote => ({ vote: vote, voters: ObjVote[vote]}))
               .map(data => <Vote ...data key={data.vote} />)` now error after vote`:`

Comment: Dont know why no I ahve problem with `<Vote ...data key={data.vote} /> `... is problem

Comment: @PawełBaca put the `{}`, like this: `<Vote {...data} key={data.vote} />` or `<Vote vote={data.vote} voters={data.voters} key={data.vote} />`

Comment: Ok it work,but I have to style each element of  `data.voters`. Do you know how ? :) `data.voters` is `EwaKJacekJacek` I need `<div>Ewa</div>` `<div>Jacek</div>`

Comment: OK everything work, thanks. I spend two days on this and you do this in 10min nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to an array using [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), and then you can map it. First you need to convert the object to an array like object, by adding the length property. To add the length property, you can use [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const ObjVote = {
  '1':['EwaK','Jacek','Jacek'],
  '2':['Anna','Pawel','EwaK'],
  '3':['Anna','EwaK','Jacek'],
  '4':['Jas','Jas','Pawel'],
  '5':['Anna','Jas','Pawel']
}

const array = Array.from(
  Object.assign( 
    {}, 
    ObjVote, 
    { length: Object.keys(ObjVote).length + 1 } // add the number of keys + 1 (the missing 0 index) as the length property 
  ),
  (voters, vote) => ({ vote, voters }) // create the vote object
).slice(1); // remove the 1st empty element

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use map on `Object`. But you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then `map`.

```js
 let ObjVote = {
  '1':['EwaK','Jacek','Jacek'],
  '2':['Anna','Pawel','EwaK'],
  '3':['Anna','EwaK','Jacek'],
  '4':['Jas','Jas','Pawel'],
  '5':['Anna','Jas','Pawel']
}

let data = Object.keys(ObjVote).map(key => {
  return {
    vote: key,
    users: ObjVote[key]
  }
})

console.log(data)
```