# "Objects are not valid as React children - use an array" - but it is an array?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render jsx via mapping through an array that has been retrieved from my database and set to local state. The error I am getting is

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id,
>   name, 
>       displayorder}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array 
>       instead.

Please see my code below...

```
class TableList extends Component {
  constructor(){
     super()

  this.state = {
    allPeopleResults: [],
    searchName: '',
    searchedNameResults: []
  }
}

  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3003/api/getPeople').then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
        this.setState({
            allPeopleResults: response.data
        })            
    })

}
<Card
 title={this.state.allPeopleResults}
 category="Here is a subtitle for this table"
 ctTableFullWidth
 ctTableResponsive
 content={
              <Table striped hover>                    
                <thead>                      
                  <tr>
                    { 
                      this.state.allPeopleResults.map((person, key) => {
                        return (
                          <div>
                            <th key={key}>{person.name}</th>
                          </div>
                          ); 
                      })
                    }  
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.allPeopleResults.map((person, key) => {
                    return (                          
                      <td key={key}>{person.name}</td>
                      )

                    }) 
                  })}
                </tbody>  
              </Table>
            }
          />
        </Col>
```

I know that my `allPeopleResults` property on state is correctly getting set with an array because the `console.log` in componentDidMount returns what I want it to, because it returns an array of objects from my database. I am aware that arrays ARE objects, but I would have thought that using the`.map` method would have done what it needed to do.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to render an array of vanilla Javascript objects as your title:

```
title={this.state.allPeopleResults}
```

Make the title a string or valid react element instead (which could be an array of React elements, but not vanilla objects).

Comment: It's always in the detail... ;)  #redherringftw

Comment: THAAAAAAAANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that what you get from database is an array?

Check if array map function is available in the prototype of you get from database, if not, it might be an indexed object?

See if this helps
[Converting a JS object to an array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array-using-jquery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)