# How to map Coordinates into an object (Angular)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, google-maps

I have the following return from an API:

```
{
"0": {
    "lat": "-30.02897288697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22800440001900000"
},
"1": {
    "lat": "-30.02879088697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22803440001900000"
},
"2": {
    "lat": "-30.02846288697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22814140001900000"
},
"3": {
    "lat": "-30.02822088697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22821640001900000"
},
"4": {
    "lat": "-30.02760388697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22844040001900000"
}
 (...continues)
```

How do I map that into an Array to use it in my Angular app? So far I've tried creating an array of this object without luck:

```
export class MyClass {
  lat: string;
  lng: string;
}
```

and...

```
handleSuccessfulResponse(response) {
  this.myClass = response;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you tell us the output you desire ?

Comment: i think what op means, is that he's getting an object returned with numeric keys, and wants to convert that to an array equivalent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a JS object to an array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857468/converting-a-js-object-to-an-array-using-jquery) (note that this question has answers which do not use jQuery)

Comment: You can use `.map` to cast new MyClass objects for your result array, or an alternative is `Object.values(response)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use method [`Objects.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) as follows:

```js
const result = {
  "0": {
    "lat": "-30.02897288697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22800440001900000"
  },
  "1": {
    "lat": "-30.02879088697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22803440001900000"
  },
  "2": {
    "lat": "-30.02846288697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22814140001900000"
  },
  "3": {
    "lat": "-30.02822088697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22821640001900000"
  },
  "4": {
    "lat": "-30.02760388697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22844040001900000"
  }
};

const myArray = Object.values(result);
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Better to add an answer to the existing duplicate than spread the answers around, no?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Object.values for this, find the snippet code for more details.

```js
let obj={
"0": {
    "lat": "-30.02897288697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22800440001900000"
},
"1": {
    "lat": "-30.02879088697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22803440001900000"
},
"2": {
    "lat": "-30.02846288697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22814140001900000"
},
"3": {
    "lat": "-30.02822088697400000",
    "lng": "-51.22821640001900000"
}}

let arr=Object.values(obj);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I think you should map over the values and return a collection of MyClass instead of just values. of the object.